# Submit Token and Smart Contract related Transactions on UI and listen on Server

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

What set up do I need for submitting transactions on client,
but listen for execution on the server like a webhook?

I want to listen on server to change status of records in my own database.

Do I need my own mirror node?

Do I need some lib other than hedera js sdk?

Answer (score 0):

> What set up do I need for submitting transactions on client

For this, you can use the Hedera JS SDK, which covers all transactions types supported by Hedera.
You can also use ethersjs or web3js if you are only interested in EVM transactions.

I'll assume that you are after all types of transactions
in the rest of this answer.

> but listen for execution on the server like a webhook?

As far as I know, there isn't a webhooks provision,
and if so, you'll need to build this yourself.

> I want to listen on server to change status of records in my own db.

The best way to do this, in your specific scenario,
would probably be to implement polling in your server.

Specifically, you aren't trying to process transactions *in general*,
but instead are trying to process *specific* transactions that your client app submits.
This means that you have a much easier job (computationally)
for your server to perform.

1. Client submits transaction to a Hedera network using Hedera JS SDK
2. Client submits transaction ID to your server
3. Server begins polling Hedera mirror nodes for this transaction ID using either Hedera JS SDK or direct mirror node APIs
4. If server receives no "status change" on the transaction (that you are looking for), continue polling
5. If server receives a "status change" (that you are looking for), stop polling and update your database.

IMO the easiest way to browse/ trial mirror node APIs is via its swagger UI.
Here's one for Hedera Testnet:

[testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/docs/#transactions](https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/docs/#transactions)

> Do I need my own mirror node?

You likely will not need to run your own mirror node for this,
since you're only interested in the transactions that you are submitting yourself.
But it really depends on the volume/ frequency of the transactions you need to process -
if it is high, it might make sense to run your own mirror node to get dedicated performance.

> Do I need some lib other than hedera js sdk?

You can use Hedera JS SDK, or if you would like to query the mirror nodes directly, you can use any HTTP library. (e.g. on NodeJs you could use `axios`.)